# Python insert value to foreign key attribute (MYSQL)

Tags: python, mysql, database

i created two table in MySQL database

Staff table:

```
+----+-----------+-------------
| ID |           NAME         |
+----+-----------+-------------
| No data available in table   |         
+----+-----------+-------------
```

Qualification table:

```
+----+----------+--------------+
| ID | title    |  staff_ID    |   
+----+----------+--------------+
|  No data available in table  | 
+----+--------------+-----------
```

ID of both table is primary key and staff_ID of qualification table is foreign key. My python code is like

```
con=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',port=3306,user='root',password='admin',db='mydb')
cursor=con.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Staff (ID,Name)VALUES (%s,%s)",(1001,"MR Tan"))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(2001,"Professor","select ID from Staff where ID=1001"))
con.commit()
cursor.close()
con.close()
```

i try to insert value to foreign key attribute but i get "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Answer (score 1):

2 ways :

You can try

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Staff (ID,Name)VALUES (%d,%s)",(1001,"MR Tan"))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES (%d,%s,%s)",(2001,"Professor","select ID from Staff where ID=1001"))
```

or

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Staff (ID,Name)VALUES (%s,%s)",("1001","MR Tan"))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",("2001","Professor","select ID from Staff where ID=1001"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you executing the `SELECT` statement. You already have the ID available. Pass it as such:

```
con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',port=3306,user='root',password='admin',db='mydb')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO Staff (ID,Name) VALUES (%d,%s)",
    (1001,"MR Tan")
)

cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO Qualification VALUES (%d,%s,%d)",
    (2001,"Professor",1001)
)
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't a call to `commit` is necessary after the first `execute`?